# Is $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})/(p\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory

Here $p$ is a prime number and $n>1$.

I know the following facts:

- $p\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime (hence maximal) ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.
- [$J$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ iff $R/J$ is a field.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Field)
- $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.

So my conjecture is that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})/(p\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. However, is seems strange to me that it would then not depend on $n$, which makes me suspect this is not true. I would have expected this quotient to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}$, but this is not a field in general. My only other guess (and this one is a shot in the dark) would be the unique finite field of order $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2, specifically the 5th statement.

Comment: This is the third isomorphism theorem (for rings/groups): $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$.

Comment: Your example involves finite rings, so we can just *count*:  $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ has size $p^n$ and $p\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ has size $p^{n-1}$. Then $(\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z)/(p\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z)$ has size $p^n/p^{n-1} = p$. Do you really find it strange that $p^n/p^{n-1}$ does not depend on $n$?

Comment: Look at a concrete example: $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$ is integers considered up to multiples of $8$ while $2\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$ is even numbers considered up to multiples of $8$.  If you think about integers up to multiples of 8 and collapse together those integers up to multiples of 8 that differ by an even number, do you agree that you're basically considering even numbers all together and odd numbers all together?  Does this result really change if you replace 8 with another power of $2$ ($2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, and so on) or in fact another even number ($2$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $10$, and so on)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on carmichael561's comment: explicitly, consider the projection

$$
\pi : m \in \mathbb{Z} \mapsto [m] \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}.
$$

Since $p^n\Z \subset p\Z$, this map factorizes through $\Z/p^n\Z$ yielding a morphism

$$
\widehat{\pi} : [m] \in \Z/p^n\Z \mapsto [m] \in \Z/p\Z.
$$

which is an epi (because $\pi$ is). Now, by the first isomorphism theorem we obtain

$$
\Z/p\Z \simeq (\Z/p^n\Z) / \ker \widehat{\pi},
$$

so it would suffice to show that $\ker \widehat{\pi} = p\Z/p^n\Z$. In effect, an element $[m] \in \Z/p^n\Z$ is in the kernel of $\widehat{\pi}$ if the class of $m$ in $\Z/p\Z$ is zero, and this occurs precisely when $m = pk$ for some integer $k \in \Z$. Since $[pk] = p[k]$, this is to say $[m] \in p\Z/p^n\Z$.

Finally, an unimportant "intuitive" remark: the ideal $p\Z$ is "large", in the sense that $p^k\Z \subset p^l\Z$ when $k> l$. The same holds for $p^k\Z/p^n\Z$ and $p^l\Z/p^n\Z$. Hence dividing by $p\Z/p^n\Z$ should produce a "small" ring (in this case, a field).

Comment: Just to clarify, $n$ in $p^n$ is not the same as in $[n]$, is that right?

Comment: @Era you are right, it is just awful notation which I will fix asap.